# Flutter ProxyProvider create failing

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

When trying to use ProxyProvider
using the example syntax given in https://pub.dev/packages/provider

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MultiProvider(
    providers: [
      ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => Counter()),
      ProxyProvider<Counter, Translations>(
        create: (_, counter, __) => Translations(counter.value),
      ),
    ],
    child: Foo(),
  );
}

class Translations {
  const Translations(this._value);

  final int _value;

  String get title => 'You clicked $_value times';
}
```

I end up having following error in create function every time:

> The argument type 'Translation Function(BuildContext, dynamic,
>   dynamic)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Translation
>   Function(BuildContext)'.dart(argument_type_not_assignable)

what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation haven't updated yet.
In v3.2.0 you should use `create` with one argument - BuildContext.
You can downgrade to 3.1.0 and continue using `builder` with 3 arguments.

old:

```
builder: (context, x, y) => ...
```

new

```
create: (context) => ...
```